# What is the Nginx Conf for Wordpress Multisites if this multisites `location` is in another `location`?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Let assume that I have the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html
`- site_a
`- site_b
`- site_c
`- multisites
```

I want to install and enable wordpress multisites under `multisites` directory.

But I cannot access to this directory, even after studying [this Nginx official settings](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/#rewrite-rules-for-multisite-using-subdirectories)

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
map $uri $blogname{
    ~^(?P<blogpath>/[^/]+/)files/(.*)       $blogpath ;
}

map $blogname $blogid{
    default -999;

    #Ref: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/
    #include /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nginx-helper/map.conf ;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost.local;
    http2 on;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    proxy_buffer_size 256k;
    proxy_buffers              4 512k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    512k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size   0;

    root /var/www/html;

    location ~* xmlrpc.php {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/#rewrite-rules-for-multisite

    location ~* /multisites {
        index index.php;

        location ~ ^(/[^/]+)?/files/(.+) {
            try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/files/$2 /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 ;
            access_log off;     log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        #avoid php readfile()
        location ^~ /multisites/blogs.dir {
            internal;
            alias /var/www/html/multisites/wp-content/blogs.dir ;
            access_log off;     log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite_log on;
            rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
            rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
            rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/(site_a|site_b)/wp-json/ {
        # if permalinks not enabled
        rewrite ^/cms/wp-json/(.*?)$ /cms/?rest_route=/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(site_a|site_b)/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$ {
            expires 365d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }

    location ~ / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$ {
            expires 365d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thank you for your help.